# MPMoviePlayerControllerの>>|ボタンの挙動について

Tags: ios, xcode

現在iOS8でMPMoviePlayerControllerを利用して動画再生機能を実現しようとしているのですが
フルスクリーンの状態で表示される>>|ボタンを長押しではなく、シングルタップすると
画面上部中央にLoading...と表示され、動画の再生ができなくなります。
（長押しでの早送りは正常に動いています。）
このシングルタップ時の挙動を無効、もしくはタップしたら再生中動画の再生終了時間まで移動する
という処理に変更することはできないでしょうか？

MPMoviePlayerControllerは下記の設定を入れています。

```
_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
_moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[_moviePlayer play];
```